# Sitecore: Storing custom user properties for AD users

Tags: active-directory, sitecore, user-profile

In Sitecore 7, how could one got about saving a custom user property for Active Directory users, when we only got "read-only" rights to the AD eg. keep the property within Sitecore scope, and not store it in the AD.

Logged in users within the domains Sitecore and Extranet, can store some settings which is saved in a custom user property within the user profile; how can we extend this functionality to cover users authenticated via Active Directory.

We are using the AD LDAP Module to authenticate AD users.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the procedure described in [this document](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/ad/11/sitecore_active_directory_module_guide_sc66-70-a4.pdf), chapter 3 "Advanced Profile configuration". In particular, the paragraph 3.2 is about custom profile properties.

To tell the long story short, you have to do the following:

- configure the profile provider
- configure the custom property in the web.config
- extend Sitecore user template to make that property visible

The document contains all the details. Just follow it thoroughly - there's a number of steps you should make to configure that feature. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but correct me if im wrong. This way seems to require a property in the AD aswell, but in our case this custom property does not exist as a AD property.

Comment: Ah, I see. In this case you can try to skip the step of configuring property in web.config (paragraph 3.2 in the document) and follow the rest of the steps the same way. The property will then live in Sitecore database, not AD domain. It's been a long time I worked with this last, so you should verify that assumption :)